# Some phrases follow a two person pattern - what are these kinds of phrases called?

Tags: phrases

In English we have some composite phrases that are meant to be said by two people. Person A says the first part and person B finishes with the appropriate response.

An example would be the classic alligator and crocodile pattern.

> Person A: "See you later alligator"
> Person B: "In a while crocodile"

Another example might be Marco, and Polo. Or from another language, a common example in Ukrainian is "Glory to Ukraine" and the response is "Glory to the Heroes".

I thought they were called "catch and call" phrases but after some searching, I dont see any good validation on that.

What are these composite phrases called?

Comment: There's a musical term "call and response" which seems close.

Comment: In certain Christian liturgies, the responses are called just that: _responses_. Thus Leader etc: "The Lord be with you."
Response (by the congregation): "And with your spirit." // I'll struggle to separate the different registers now; I can just imagine Python doing a sanctimonious "See you later alligator" ... "In a while crocodile".

Comment: I would call the second part the 'traditional response' or 'traditional reply'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linguistics, this is called an **adjacency pair**:

> **adjacency pair** *n.*
> *Linguistics.*
>  Two successive utterances by different speakers, where the second is a necessary or expected response to the first, as
> in an exchange of greetings.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

In 1937’s [*A Dictionary Of Slang And Unconventional English*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.460523), lexicographer Eric Partridge calls the “person B” part—the expected response—a *dovetail*. (And later, a *dovetail response*.) (Search `"dovetail"` at the above link.)

In 1977’s [*A Dictionary of Catch Phrases, British and American, from the Sixteenth Century to the Present Day*](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryofcatc00part), he applies the term *dovetail* to *in a while, crocodile*. (Search `"see you later alligator"` at the above link.)